# VpnClientSetupAMD64.exe missing in Azure point-to-site VPN download

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-vpn

I am trying to setup my first Azure point-to-site VPN. If I'm reading things correctly, the URL I get from this PowerShell code:

```
$profile = New-AzVpnClientConfiguration -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $GWName -AuthenticationMethod "EapTls"
$profile.VPNProfileSASUrl
```

should download an executable called **VpnClientSetupAMD64.exe** that will be in the **WindowsAmd64** folder of the downloaded zip file. That executable should do the setup on the native Win 10 1909 client.

The zip file I get doesn't have any executable in it and doesn't have that directory in it. I only get the XML and OVPN files with the config data for the VPN client.

I also tried using the **Download VPN Client** selection in the GUI Azure portal on the VnetGW/point-to-site page and I get the identical zip file - still no setup exe.

I looked for a way to either directly download the **VpnClientSetupAMD64.exe** file or to specify the **azurevpnconfig.xml** file that I do get as a parameter to setup the VPN client but I see nothing applicable.

I understand that I can manually configure the VPN client using the info I have but that doesn't scale.

Can someone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be default, the `Tunnel type` is **OpenVPN(SSL)** in the Point-to-site configuration UI. Before you [generate files using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert#zipps), you should select the `VpnClientProtocol` to **SSTP** and **IKEv2**, or one of them because they are used for **Windows clients**. So you will get the **VpnClientSetupAMD64.exe** file. You could get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps#creategateway).

You also could refer to [create a VPN Gateway and add point-to-site configuration using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/scripts/vpn-gateway-sample-point-to-site-certificate-authentication-powershell).

```
New-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -Name VNet1GW -ResourceGroupName TestRG1 `
 -Location 'East US' -IpConfigurations $gwipconfig -GatewayType Vpn `
 -VpnType RouteBased -GatewaySku VpnGw1 -VpnClientProtocol "IKEv2"
# Add the VPN client address pool
$Gateway = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $GWName
Set-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -VirtualNetworkGateway $Gateway -VpnClientAddressPool $VPNClientAddressPool
# Create a self-signed root certificate
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature `
 -Subject "CN=P2SRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
 -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 `
 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign
# Export the root certificate to "C:\cert\P2SRootCert.cer"
# Upload the root certificate public key information
$P2SRootCertName = "P2SRootCert.cer"
$filePathForCert = "C:\cert\P2SRootCert.cer"
$cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($filePathForCert)
$CertBase64 = [system.convert]::ToBase64String($cert.RawData)
$p2srootcert = New-AzVpnClientRootCertificate -Name $P2SRootCertName -PublicCertData $CertBase64
Add-AzVpnClientRootCertificate -VpnClientRootCertificateName $P2SRootCertName `
 -VirtualNetworkGatewayname "VNet1GW" `
 -ResourceGroupName "TestRG1" -PublicCertData $CertBase64
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to setup Azure P2S VPN today, the downloaded VPN client is just a configuration file.

Did a bit research and found the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-client

Open Windows store, and install a app "Azure VPN Client". Then you can run Azure VPN Client and import the configuration file.